# $x \circ y^{-1}$ isometry for constant parametrisation

Tags: differential-geometry

We can use the following parametrisations for a chart,
\begin{equation}
x(u,v) = (u,v,0), \quad (u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y(\rho, \theta) = (\rho\cos{\theta}, \rho\sin{\theta},0)
\end{equation}
With first fundamental forms $E,F,G$ and $\bar{E}, \bar{F}, \bar{G}$ respectively. Now, we have that
\begin{equation}
E = \bar{E} = 1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
F = \bar{F} = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
G = 1, \quad \bar{G} = \rho^2
\end{equation}
Now, I want to use the following proposition to determine whether $x \circ y^{-1}$ is an isometry. (as local isometry implies (global) isometry).

[image]

Now, it it correct to say that $x \circ y^{-1}$ is an isometry if and only if $\rho^2 = 1$, (so: $\rho = 1$  is constant) or should I say it is not an isometry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proposition says if the equality holds in all $U$ it is an isometry, but just by this proposition you cannot say it is an isometry.

But there is a "reciprocal" for this proposition, more specifically it is the exercise 2 of do Carmo's differential geometry book:

"Let $\varphi:S\to \overline{S}$ be an isometry an $x:U\to S$ a parametrization at $p\in S$. Then $\overline{x}=\varphi\circ x$ is a parametrization at $\varphi(p)$ and $E=\overline{E}$, $F=\overline{F}$, $G=\overline{G}$."

By this, if $x\circ y^{-1}$ were an isometry, then we would have $E=\overline{E}$, $F=\overline{F}$, $G=\overline{G}$.